# How to add custom page attributes in WordPress?

Tags: customization, theme-development, themes

I would like to add some custom page attributes for each page in my theme.
For exmaple:

- A checkbox 'Display Featured image'
- A input field to write a custom value for an subheadline.

How can I achieve this?

[image: Preview]